# removeEventListener undefined reference

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm creating a large grid of divs which I plan to perform animations and effects on. I have around 90 divs creating a tiled background. Now here's the trick with this..I am creating the page to be responsive. I cannot float these divs and so they are inline-blocked with overflow hidden. So as the width of the viewport changes the amount of divs in the rows changes - essentially moving the div over and down. So I've had to dynamically populate the div text based on position(x,y). Unfortunately I am having an issue with the event listener box moving because of this.

When I try to remove the event listener I get an undefined error - even when I move it into the initial listener scope.

```
        function menuBox(){

    var allDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    var menuDiv1 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 16);
    var menuDiv2 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 120); //Blank Div
    var menuDiv3 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 225);
    var menuDiv4 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 329);
    var menuDiv5 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 433);
    var menuDiv6 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 538);
    var menuDiv7 = document.elementFromPoint(39, 642);

    var menuDiv = [
        menuDiv1,
        menuDiv3,
        menuDiv4,
        menuDiv5,
        menuDiv6,
        menuDiv7
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++) {
        allDiv[i].innerHTML = '';
        // allDiv[i].removeEventListener("mouseover", menuOver, false);
        // allDiv[i].removeEventListener("mouseout", menuOut, false);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < menuDiv.length; i++) {
        menuDiv[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function menuOver(){
            TweenLite.to(this, 0.4, {backgroundColor: '#272822', color: '#fff', scale: 1.1})
        }, false);
        menuDiv[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function menuOut(){
            TweenLite.to(this, 0.3, {backgroundColor: '#fff', color: '#000', scale: 1})
        }, false);
    };

    menuDiv1.innerHTML = '<p>Switch<br>Menu</p>';
    menuDiv3.innerHTML = '<p>Michael</p>';
    menuDiv4.innerHTML = '<p>Design</p>';
    menuDiv5.innerHTML = '<p>Develop</p>';
    menuDiv6.innerHTML = '<p>Imaging</p>';
    menuDiv7.innerHTML = '<p>Motion</p>';

    console.log('menuBox function');

};

menuBox();
window.onresize = menuBox;
```

Comment: is `Uncaught ReferenceError: menuOver is not defined` the error you got in console???

Comment: Yes! I named the function and thought it was defined.

Comment: so now the problem is resolved or not?

Comment: No nothing has changed since I posted this

Answer (score 0):

You should know that, to remove event handlers from DOM element, the function specified with the `addEventListener()` method must be an **external function** .
Anonymous functions, like `domelement.removeEventListener("event", function(){ \\something });` will not work.

Having said that, same mistake has been done in your code, thus leading to reference type of error `Uncaught ReferenceError: menuOver is not defined`. 
To make you code work, below are changes you should use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++) {
   allDiv[i].innerHTML = '';
   allDiv[i].removeEventListener("mouseover", menuOver, false);
   allDiv[i].removeEventListener("mouseout", menuOut, false);
};

for (var i = 0; i < menuDiv.length; i++) {
   menuDiv[i].addEventListener("mouseover",menuOver, false);
   menuDiv[i].addEventListener("mouseout",menuOut, false);
};

function menuOver(){
  TweenLite.to(this, 0.4, {backgroundColor: '#272822', color: '#fff', scale: 1.1});
}
function menuOut(){
  TweenLite.to(this, 0.3, {backgroundColor: '#fff', color: '#000', scale: 1});
}
```